# Deleting annotation data from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a function that will delete a user annotation that they have previously added. Currently, I am able to delete the annotation and from the map and the annotation data from firebase. However, once this function is completed a crash appears.

The error that occurs is "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10faab8c8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10faab288)."

Comment: Could you please post your annotation fetching code?

Comment: I have posted my annotation fetch code

Comment: I don't see your annotation code? Anyways, somewhere you are force unwrapping your snapshot as a NSDictionary when the value is Null. This is most likely happening because your `.value` block is fired when you delete the annotation.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast a nil value `NSNull` to a dictionary. This is most likely happening somewhere else in your code. Probably when you are fetching your annotation. If you are fetching your annotation with a `.value` block, then it would make sense for this crash to occur since a `.value` block will be called when data is [deleted as well](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Enums/FIRDataEventType#/c:@E@FIRDataEventType@FIRDataEventTypeValue).

Comment: Okay thank you, I am fetching my annotation with a `.value` block. Does this mean I replaced `.value` with `childRemoved`. Apologies if that is incorrect, I am not massively experience with coding